# How to use input datetime?

Tags: html, forms, datetime, input

In documentation I found the `datetime` input type:

> `datetime`: [html5](/questions/tagged/html5) A control for entering a date and time (hour, minute, second, and fraction of a second) based on UTC time zone.
>
> `datetime-local`: [html5](/questions/tagged/html5) A control for entering a date and time, with no time zone.

However, when I try to use one of them, I see not difference between `datetime` and `text` input types.

#### HTML

```
<input type="datetime" name="" id="test">        
<input type="datetime-local" name="" id="test1">
```

#### Result

> [image]

Why `datetime` input type doesn't work as supposed?

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/f9Udv/1/)

Comment: Aren't you getting the calendar control when input type is datetime? You won't get it and the automatic validation if the input type is text. Also note that it would work only if your browser supports html5.

Comment: @Bobz79 The calendar is now shown. The input type is `datetime`, as you can see in the jsfiddle. I am running Chromium latest version.

Comment: Ah ok, I didnt realize that it is being shown only when type is datetime-local and not for datetime. It seems the implementation is not fully done for many browsers, including chrome.
http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Comment: Perhaps the local time zone needs to be set in the environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`datetime` still has almost [no support in modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/input-datetime). I run some tests and it works only in Chrome and it's very ugly and buggy there.

I'd recommend you to use a js date picker plugin instead.

Comment: Running `Chrome Version 34.0.1847.116 Ubuntu 14.04 aura (260972)` - shouldn't it work?

Comment: It says right there that the support is only partial: http://caniuse.com/input-datetime it's just a working draft. Why would you want to use it?

Comment: I haven't said that I want to use it. :-) I just wanted to know how to use it, how it works.

Comment: Vou shouldn't use datetime most browser vendors won't support it in the future iOS7 has removed it. About datetime-local you can and should use it and use a polyfill (http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/demos/cfgs/input-datetime-local.html). There is nothing wrong about beeing a working draft. input type datetime-local is a very stable part of HTML5 and it's more stable than header/footer/section or video element.

Comment: It is not supported by Chrome either on most platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Go the following link and check your browser compatiblity.Then use it

```
Supported
Not supported
Partially supported
Support unknown  

http://caniuse.com/#search=datetime
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the latest version of browsers like *Firefox(29.0)* and *Chromium(34.0)* has **not yet provided the implementation** of `<input type="datetime">`.

Chromium(Chrome) supports `datetime-local` but not `datetime`. Maybe that's because `datetime` **requires browser to provide interface to select time-zone along with date and time**.

I expect the support will be provided in the upcoming versions of the browsers.

Answer (score 1):

`<input type=datetime>` still isn’t supported by most browsers, or the [support](http://caniuse.com/input-datetime) is limited and buggy. The usefulness of this type has been debated heavily, and use cases seem to be too rare to make browser vendors interested enough. It was marked as being “at risk” in HTML5 CR, and the [newest CR](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140429/) (29 April 2014) has dropped it (as well as `type=datetime-local`).

The conclusion is: don’t use it, except perhaps in a controlled environment where users are known to have browser that support it. You might consider using two fields, one for date and another for time, though this isn’t quite the same of course.